# R: extracting values according to column name and row name basis

Tags: r, extract

I understand that you can extract data from a dataframe on a `[x,y]` coordinate basis, such as:

`df[[144]][[1]]`

I also understand that you can extract data from a dataframe on a column name basis, such as:

`df$column.name[[row.num]]` or `df[["column.name"]][[row.num]]`

Is there a way you can extract data from a dataframe on a column name AND row name basis? Something like:

`df[["column.name"]][["row.name"]]` (this does not work btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df['row.name', 'column.name']
```

Using an example from `mtcars` dataset

```
mtcars['Valiant', 'mpg']
#[1] 18.1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use  `match`

```
df[["column.name"]][match("row.name", row.names(df))]
```

Using the `mtcars` example

```
mtcars[['mpg']][match('Valiant', row.names(mtcars))]
#[1] 18.1
```